# Does cooking or baking with honey make it toxic?

Tags: baking, heat, honey

I've heard that cooking honey or baking with it makes food or baked products toxic.If it is true,then how can we use honey while baking cookies or cakes that does not affect the quality of these?

Comment: Please explain where you heard this - do you have a source or is this hearsay? And remember: we will accept questions about *food safety*, but not about *mid- or long term health*.

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37216/is-honey-toxic-when-heated-up-in-tea

Answer (score 2):

Baking with honey is not toxic (as far as I know).

However, burning honey to the point of carbonization might be - it will release nasty black fumes.

That said, the same would happen with any other sugar, or mostly any food if you burn it to the point it's black. So it's as harmful (or harmless) as any ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, baking something with honey or cooking with it doesn't make it toxic. Honey could lost its health benefits, that's all.

Comment: Where do you find that health benefits are lost?